# all my settings and preferences disapear in TOR 6.0

Tags: mac

I have a mac (OSX yosemite) and downloaded the last version of TOR 6.0. Usually, when there's a new version, all my preferences, settings and bookmarks remain in the new one. But this time, everything disapeared, and I used my back up to find the previous version, with all my preferences.
It's such a job to do it all over again!
did that happen to anyone else? how can I download the 6.0 version of TOR and still keep all that stuff?
thanks for your help............

Comment: This may be related to [Ticket #13252](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13252), I don't have a solid answer, but it might point you in the right direction.